# Logging out from different routes don't change screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

My Top level widgets are providers and their child is Material App. In Material app as home route I am checking from my auth provider Whether user is logged in so I show different screen then. And in my drawer I have a logout button to logout user and notify listener. If I just start the app logout works but if I navigate to some other routes then logout didnt take me to auth screen.

```
return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'IBM Plex Sans',
        textTheme: const TextTheme(
          headline1: TextStyle(
            color: primaryColor,
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          ),
          caption: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15,
            color: Colors.grey,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          ),
        ),
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFCAA32),
        ),
      ),
      home: authData.isAuth ? CatagoriesScreen() : AuthScreen(),
```

Comment: Is `authData` coming from one of your providers? Please share the code how do access this provider.

Comment: Without seeing the full code I would suggest to check if you are using an consumer etc. to get changes of the isAuth value

Comment: @EnviroApps Yes, I am using consumer.

Comment: @PeterKoltai I was using consumer, now I changed to Provider.of<Auth>(context). Still it is not working.

Comment: I checked my logout functionality is working fine, it indeed notify listeners. my isAuth function called too it also returns false, but the problem is it is not updating the screen after even getting false from isAuth. It only works if I just login and then I logout.  If I route to different page from my drawer, it stops working.

Comment: Are you sure it is not working? Did you check with widget inspector that `home` is changed or not when logging out? If you add pages to the navigation stack, these are not cleared automatically on logging out. In case of a logout it might be necessary to reset navigation stack to show home route.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by providing key: `UniqueKey()` to material app.